# GoPro why high frame rate does not reduce time

Tags: framerate

On latest GoPro 4 Silver with 64 GB

when i set 1080p 30fps i get estimated 4 hour recording time but when i double the framerate it not only does not shoren it actually increases so with 1080p 60fps it shows ~4.5 hour.

How is that?

Comment: I'm not sure why you would expect an increase in frame rate to result in a decrease in time. How would that work? The frame rate should have no effect on the duration -- recording an hour of video results in... an hour of video.

Comment: He's assuming (not unreasonably) that more frames will occupy more disk space and hence result in a lower capacity.

Comment: @Mulvya  Ah, so "recording time" means "available capacity". Got it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The GoPro4 Silver model uses the [same bitrate](https://gopro.com/support/articles/hero4-silver-recording-time-in-each-video-setting) for 1080p-30 as 1080p-60 and hence the recording times are similar. This does mean that fewer bits are allocated per frame in the 60fps mode, although since the codec H264 uses inter-frame compression, the difference won't be as stark.

Comment: Thanks that explains it, i assumed that it uses that even if i put on 30 frames, but i could not understand how could 30fps version have less capacity than 60fps, it actually got lower it didnt remain on the same number, i'd just see that on 30fps i can take like 30minutes less video, which is naturally strange :)